# Travar para não arrastar no sortable

Tags: jquery-ui

Esta semana recebi a ajuda do Lúcio Rubens com uma dúvida, ele me ajudou com este código, para pegar os IDs dos elementos clicados.

Agora em cima deste mesmo código, estou precisando travar uma UL para que ela não permita que sejam retirados mais elementos,

Este é o exemplo funcionando, [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fzsrq2a9/1/)

```
$(".items").sortable({
    connectWith: ".items",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        var id_origem = ui.sender.attr("id"),
            id_clicado = ui.item.attr("id"),
            id_destino = $(this).attr("id");
    }
});
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o quê e quando queres fazer esse bloqueio? está pouco claro para mim.

Comment: Marcus, o Michel resolveu para mim, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No exemplo no link abaixo, inserí uma classe block para não permitir a retirada dele, desta forma, ele recebe os itens mas não deixa sair dele.

http://jsfiddle.net/sw4gs7nh/

Comment: E isso memo Michel, agora vou tentar trabalhar com ela para avisar se a pessao tentar retirar alguma coisa ali de dentro, obrigado pela ajuda!